# How do I list images (tags) in a remote Google Cloud docker repo?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I call this command to send my image to a repo.

`docker push gcr.io/my-project/my-images:v1`

It succeeds, as in fact I can apply a "Deployment" yaml and my new service is available at GKE.

My question: How do I list the images (tags) at that gcr.io repo address, to confirm that mine is there?

`docker image list` gives me the local list, but not the remote list.

`gcloud --project=my-project container images list` gives an empty result. (Yet, as stated, my  image *is* out there.)

How can I get this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `--repository` flag

```
 --repository=REPOSITORY
    The name of the repository. Format: *.gcr.io/repository. Defaults to
    gcr.io/<project>, for the active project.
```

This example will return all the available images:

```
gcloud container images list --repository=gcr.io/your-project
NAME
gcr.io/your-project/your-image
gcr.io/your-project/another-image
gcr.io/your-project/one-more-image
```

If you want to list all the **tags** for the specified image, run

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/your-project/your-image
DIGEST        TAGS     TIMESTAMP
0109315b26cf  5a9ad92  2018-11-15T13:24:56
98e2d1475275  343fca4  2018-11-15T11:35:52
df58b7269b89  d96aa6c  2018-11-14T17:11:18
47e93cb3a33f  7a9ff9d  2018-11-13T16:27:06
```

Comment: Thanks, but running "gcloud container images list --repository=gcr.io/my-project" just gives  me "NAME\ngcr.io/fuf-automation/my-project" and nothing else. Yet this is right after I did  docker push commands, and my new code is indeed running.

Comment: Thank you! The key  point is that I was confused  between listing images and listing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `my-project` and `my-image` as appropriate and execute:

```
curl -sL https://gcr.io/v2/my-project/my-image/tags/list
```

With some `jq` command piping you can then get only what you need, if this is part of some automation.

Reference: [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags)

I got "v1 Registry API is disabled" error in my tests trying the HTTP API v1 against `gcr.io`.

Comment: But what about authentication? I get the expected denial ---   "errors:[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Failed to read tags for host 'gcr.io', repository '/v2/....